# Newbie help with Rails/Ruby. Totally lost! (Mongrel related, I think) 503 Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongrel

I am on the verge of actually hiring someone to fix this
for me, but I hope it doesn't come to that.

I have no experience with Rails/Ruby, but I do know my way around
computers in general.

I have two domains on one server (Hostingrails, I am beginning to hate
them more and more these days).

My secondary domain works 100% fine.

But for the past few days, my primary domain has not been working, it
has been giving me 503 Errors. I've opened a ticket regarding this, and
they told me to SSH into my server and reset "Mongrel". I've done this
using the code they gave me; "mongrel_rails start -d -e production
-p13930"

It seemed to have worked, but the problem was still there. The log says
the error is something about:

```
"require': no such file to load -- dispatcher (LoadError)"
```

I've re-opened a ticket concerning this, and Hostingrails basically told
me that it is not their problem anymore and that it's solely up to me to
fix it. Brilliant.

So I spent a good part of the day looking and changing things around
through SSH (probably wasn't the greatest idea) but I still keep getting
503'd on my website.

However, I recently found out that my index file HAS to be index.html,
or it will not render the page. index.htm or index.php will result in a
503. If I set the index page to index.html, it worked. Which is strange,
my htaccess file allowed for all.

Another problem, I think I have inadvertently changed something in my
settings while I was SSH'd in. When I do "bundle install" it installs
the gems into my own private webspace, for example /home/mywebsite. But
I believe on my shared plan, all the rails/ruby/gems etc are all under
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/ which I don't think I have access to.
How do I change the directory to the default one? For example, before
the error log said:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in
`require': no such file to load -- dispatcher (LoadError)
```

Now it says:

```
/home/mysite/.gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in
`require': no such file to load -- dispatcher (LoadError)
```

I think that's everything for now. Here are the rails installed on my
server by the host:

```
Installed at (3.0.0): /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0
(2.3.8): /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0
```

(again, I think my mongrel is looking in the wrong place, as my gems are
now being installed into /home/mywebsite/ instead of
/usr/local/rvm/gems/) Is it possible to someone reset the settings I've
changed back into my host's default one?

Would anyone be willing to take the time and try and fix this with me? I
am pretty annoyed at Hostingrails, since I didn't do anything to create
this problem, and they are outright refusing to help me. Why is my
primary domain getting 503 errors when my secondary domain works fine?

Answer (score 1):

Mongrel is not compatible to ruby 1.9.2. You need use a fork of mongrel to use it https://github.com/kyusik/mongrel_cluster

I advice you to user thin/passenger or unicorn instead of mongrel.

I found a little blog post about problem with Mongrel and ruby 1.9.2 http://xaop.com/blog/2010/08/04/deploying-rails-3-on-ruby-1-9-2/

Comment: Hi,

This may sound stupid, but what exactly is a  "fork" of mongrel? I've downloaded Mongrel from that site, and I am unaware where to put the folder in my server. What is the command for installing this new Mongrel while I am SSH'd into the server?

Comment: it's another mongrel gem but with some patch from another guy. Not the official maintener. It's not simple to use it. You need install this gem by gem install mongrel.gem and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try using Ruby 1.8.7 - it causes less trouble in general at this time.

Not an answer to your question in particular, but if you're new to Ruby and Rails, then hosting your own stuff can be a daunting task.

Instead, try [Heroku](http://heroku.com) - simply push your Rails app to Heroku with git and you're good to go. They support custom domainnames for free.

Comment: Hi,

What would I need to do to downgrade to 1.8.7? Also, I'm not hosting things myself, as I have a hosting plan with Hostingrails. What exactly is Heroku for? Is this for local servers only?

Comment: Your hosting provider seems to be using rvm. You could possibly just do rvm 1.8.7. Try rvm list and see which versions are available to you

Comment: I was with Hosting rails for a while, you can create a file in the directory, `.rvmrc`, and specify the version to use in there.

http://hostingrails.com/Using-Different-Ruby-Versions-with-RVM

I'd like to add that I left Hosting Rails, because their support has become atrocious. I would get out of there ASAP.
You might consider Rails Playground, I've never had a ticket take longer than 2 hours to be resolved. They even opened an external port for me on a shared server!

Comment: Well I switched back to 1.8.7 and restarted Mongrel, it doesn't seem to have helped. It also asked me to install the bundle, which still leads me to believe that rails is looking for the gems in the wrong place, since the host already provides with the basic ones. How do I change the directory in which the rails look for gems?